# How to combine UNION and INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, union

I'm fetching the grandparent of all nodes in a tree as follows:

```
SELECT P.id, P.parent, GP.parent gp_id FROM product_groups P             
INNER JOIN product_groups GP ON P.parent = GP.id
```

There is no entry with `id=0` in the table, but some where `parent=0`, indicating roots of the trees. Those rows are not fetched by this query, as there's no grandparent to join them with. I'd like those rows returned, with `0` (or `NULL`) for both `parent` and `gp_id`.

I was planning to `UNION` the second table with `(0,0)`, but can't figure out the syntax. How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT P.id, P.parent, GP.parent gp_id FROM product_groups P             
LEFT JOIN product_groups GP ON P.parent = GP.id
```

That will return all rows from `P` and any non-matching rows in `GP` will have `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT P.id, P.parent, 
       GP.parent, GP.gp_id 
  FROM product_groups P             
       INNER JOIN product_groups GP
          ON P.parent = GP.id
UNION
SELECT P.id, P.parent, 
       0 AS GP.parent, 0 AS gp_id 
  FROM product_groups P
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM product_groups GP 
                    WHERE P.parent = GP.id
                  );
```

Comment: Of course I could union two different selects. I wanted to union the table that I join. The union of multiple complete selects would not work well in my actual case.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure your objective is different than the application of the query below, but this answers the title of the question, not the content, and works for me as a UNION between 2 tables and a JOIN on the grouped results, good for when you have a backup of historical data in a side table and want to get all data in a single query, although it might be slow for big tables

```
SELECT PG.category_name, COUNT(distinct(P.id)) 
FROM 
(SELECT id, category_id FROM product_groups 
 UNION 
 SELECT  id, category_id FROM product_groups_backup) AS P
INNER JOIN product_categories PC ON P.category_id = PC.id
GROUP BY PG.category_name
```

Selecting recursive data in the same table is as JNK says, better done with a LEFT JOIN instead.

Answer (score -3):

This will return all the lines of the two tables. You can change the aliases so that you get the column name you want.

```
SELECT t1.col1 as name, t1.col2, t1.col3 
FROM t1 

UNION ALL 

SELECT t2.cola as name, t2.colb, null 
FROM t2;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.